# USART embedded C. trigger character to store array

Tags: c, embedded

USART embedded c for atmega328p. trying to store an array of 10 characters of whatever user inputs after a certain character is received(in my case char $). This compiles for me but only outputs dollar signs when I input a string of chars using hercules utility reader. any help appreciated

the following is a copy of the code I am using

```
#define FOSC 16000000 // Clock Speed
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR FOSC/16/BAUD-1

#include <avr/io.h>
//#include <stdio.h>

char trig='$';
char arr[10];

//This function is used to initialize the USART
//at a given UBRR value
void USARTInit(unsigned int ubrr)
{
    //Set Baud rate
    UBRR0H = (ubrr>>8);
    UBRR0L = ubrr;

    //Enable The receiver and transmitter
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0);
    // Set fram format: 8data 2stopBit
    UCSR0C = (1<<USBS0)|(3<<UCSZ00);
}

//This function is used to read the available data
//from USART. This function will wait untill data is
//available.
unsigned char USARTReadChar( void )
{
    //Wait untill a data is available

    while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)))
    {
        //Do nothing
    } 

    //Now USART has got data from host
    //and is available is buffer

    return UDR0;
}

//This function writes the given "data" to
//the USART which then transmit it via TX line
void USARTWriteChar(unsigned char data)
{
    //Wait untill the transmitter is ready

    while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)))
    {
        //Do nothing
        PORTD ^= 1 << PINB2;
    }

    //Now write the data to USART buffer

    UDR0 = data;
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= 1 << PINB2;

    //Varriable Declaration
    char data;

    USARTInit(MYUBRR);   

    //Loop forever

    while(1)
    {
        //Read data
        data = USARTReadChar();
        int i =0;

        //if incoming data is a dollar sign(trig),
        if(data==trig)
        {
            //start a loop to collect data from buffer
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                //array has 10 elements, will fill up the ith element as   per for loop
                arr[i]=data;
                // printf("arrayoutput %c\n",arr[i]);
                USARTWriteChar(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I edited the while loop as suggested by oleg but still cannot get it to return the array .the entire code is as follows:

```
#define FOSC 16000000 // Clock Speed
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR FOSC/16/BAUD-1
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char trig='$';
char arr[10];
//This function is used to initialize the USART
//at a given UBRR value
void USARTInit(unsigned int ubrr)
{
   //Set Baud rate

    UBRR0H = (ubrr>>8);
    UBRR0L = ubrr;

   //Enable The receiver and transmitter
  UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0);
  // Set fram format: 8data 2stopBit
  UCSR0C = (1<<USBS0)|(3<<UCSZ00);
}

//This function is used to read the available data
//from USART. This function will wait untill data is
//available.
unsigned char USARTReadChar( void )
{
   //Wait untill a data is available

   while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)))
   {
      //Do nothing
   }

   //Now USART has got data from host
   //and is available is buffer

   return UDR0;
}


//This function writes the given "data" to
//the USART which then transmit it via TX line
void USARTWriteChar(unsigned char data)
{
   //Wait untill the transmitter is ready

   while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)))
   {
      //Do nothing
          PORTD ^= 1 << PINB2;

   }

   //Now write the data to USART buffer

   UDR0 = data;
}

int main(void)
{
DDRB |= 1 << PINB2;

   //Varriable Declaration
   char data;

   USARTInit(MYUBRR);   

   //Loop forever

      //Read data

      char input[10];
      while(1){
          data = USARTReadChar();
          if(data == trig){
              for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                  //here we're saving 10 characters to input array
                  input[i] = USARTReadChar();
                   USARTWriteChar(input[i]);//tested without this also
              }
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: If you want to input the rest of the data after the $ in that for() loop then you of course need to call USARTReadChar() inside that loop.

Comment: It's possible that your blocking write may cause you to miss incoming characters, though I'd expect somewhat erratic behavior as a result.  Also, are you sure you want to be configured with **2 stop bits?**

Comment: i used the 2stop bits as it was the setup from the setup example from the datasheet.  the code worked fine when i just had the while loop transmitting back the exact character that was received.but having trouble with setting up the array part. i need to do this to eventually compare to to four constant arrays and if they are equal will trigger outputs to ports. the simple while loop for transmitting what was received is                                                             while(1)
   {
      //Read data
       data = USARTReadChar();
      USARTWriteChar(data);
      }

Answer (score 1):

Try to read chars in for() loop:

```
char input[10];
while(1){
    data = USARTReadChar();
    if(data == trig){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            //here we're saving 10 characters to input array
            input[i] = USARTReadChar();
        }
        /* UPD: write stored array to console */
        for(int i =0; i < 10; i++){
            USARTWriteChar(input[i]);
        }
        /* those symbols are needed to emulate Enter button */
        USARTWriteChar('\r');
        USARTWriteChar('\n');
     }
 }
```

UPD: this code does exactly that you asked. It stores 10 chars in memory. To return them to console (utility reader) you have to use USARTWriteChar().

Comment: no didnt seem to work, changed the while loop to the above code but didnt get any return value on utility reader. tried putting in  USARTWriteChar(input[i]); to see if this would give the value of the array but no return

Comment: Update your question with the *exact* code you are currently testing.